# C++ wrapper around Objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, linker, objective-c++

I'm trying to create a window for an OS X application written in C++ (currently using Xcode 6.4). After reading up on StackOverflow and elsewhere about Objective-C++, PIMPL and creating the appropriate C++ interface/wrapper for my Objective-C classes and objects, I came up with the following:

main.cpp:

```
#include "WindowController.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    WindowController *windowController = new WindowController();
    return 0;
}
```

WindowController.h:

```
#ifndef _WindowController_h
#define _WindowController_h

class WindowController
{
public:
    WindowController();
    ~WindowController();

    void init();
    void createWindow(int width, int height);
    void destroyWindow();

};

#endif
```

WindowController-objc.h:

```
#ifndef _WindowController_objc_h
#define _WindowController_objc_h

@interface WindowControllerObjC : NSObject

- (void) WindowController::createWindowWithWidth: (int) width
AndHeight: (int) height;

@end

#endif
```

WindowController.mm:

```
#import "WindowController.h"
#import "WindowController-objc.h"

@implementation WindowControllerObjC

AppView view;

WindowController::WindowController() {}

WindowController::~WindowController() {
    [(id)self dealloc];
}

void WindowController::init(void) {
    self = [[RTRTWindowController alloc] init];
}

void WindowController::createWindow(int width, int height) {
    (id)self createWindowWithWidth: width AndHeight: height];
}

void WindowController::destroyWindow(void) {
    // remove window
}

- (void) createWindowWithWidth: (int) width AndHeight: (int) height {
    // create window and initialize view
}
```

My original post was about resolving this linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "WindowController::WindowController()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

5 minutes after posting, I found that I had left out WindowController.mm from "Compile Sources" in the target, so the compiler was never even looking at WindowController.mm to begin with. That would be why the linker is complaining about not being able to find the constructor (*sigh*).

However for the sake of progeny, I would like to leave this post up (and the linker error) and expand this post to the topic of making C++ wrappers around Objective-C object. From what I can tell, the inverse has gotten a lot of attention, but this particular problem hasn't been treated so well.

I can probably fix all the lovely errors above myself from here on out, but for the sake of having this on StackOverflow for others, if anyone who knows much more than I do about this subject would like to use this example for a thorough walkthrough of the subject (or correct my errors), that would be fantastic!

Comment: Have you added all the required framework?

Comment: Just updated my post - I had indeed, but I forgot to tell the compiler to look at WindowController.mm in the first place! It's always something like that